# Inverse of the Toeplitz matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am working on the inverse of the sum of an identity matrix and a Toepltz matrix, and trying to find the formula for the (1,1) element of the inverse. For example, Assume $c$ is a nonzero constant, and let $$A_{t}=cI_{t}+\Omega_{t},$$ where, for $t=4$,

$$
\Omega _{t}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & \rho  & \rho ^{2} & \rho ^{3} \\
\rho  & 1 & \rho  & \rho ^{2} \\
\rho ^{2} & \rho  & 1 & \rho  \\
\rho ^{3} & \rho ^{2} & \rho  & 1%
\end{array}%
\right), \quad
\text{with} \quad \left\vert \rho \right\vert <1.
$$

In general, the $(i,j)$-th element of $\Omega _{t}$ is given by $\rho ^{|i-j|}$.

Is there any way to find a general formula for the $(1,1)$-th element of $A_{t}^{-1}$ for different $t,$ say, $t=2,3,4,\ldots ?$

Many thanks!

Comment: For $c$ sufficiently large, you can express the inverse as a convergent series on the powers of $\Omega_t$

Comment: Thanks! In my setting, \c is a fixed constant

Comment: Do we know if $|c| > (1 + |\rho|)^2$?

Comment: We don't have restrictions on c as long as it is nonzero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), $U_t=A_t^{-1}(1,1)$ is given by the ratios of two determinants. Let:

$$A_3=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}c+1&\rho&\rho^2 \\ \rho&c+1&\rho\\ \rho^2&\rho&c+1\end{array}\right),\qquad B_3=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&\rho&\rho^2 \\ \rho&c+1&\rho\\ \rho^2&\rho&c+1\end{array}\right)$$
and define $A_t,B_t$ in a similar fashion. By replacing the first column with the first column minus $\rho$ times the second column, then expanding along the first column, we get:
$$ \det A_{t+1} = (c+1-\rho^2) \det A_t + c\rho^2 \det B_t, $$
$$ \det B_{t+1} = (1-\rho^2) \det A_t + c\rho^2 \det B_t, $$
and by eliminating $B_t$,
$$ \det A_{t+1} = (c+1+c\rho^2-\rho^2) \det A_t -c^2\rho^2\det A_{t-1} $$
then dividing the whole line by $\det A_t$,
$$ \frac{1}{U_{t+1}} = (c+1+c\rho^2-\rho^2)-c^2\rho^2 U_{t} $$
or:

> $$ U_{t+1} =\frac{1}{(c+1+c\rho^2-\rho^2)-(c^2\rho^2)U_t}$$

where obviously $U_1=\frac{1}{c+1}$. If we set $U_t=\frac{V_t}{c\rho},$

$$ V_{t+1} =\frac{1}{\frac{c+1+c\rho^2-\rho^2}{c\rho}-V_t},$$
so by setting $\beta=\frac{c+1+c\rho^2-\rho^2}{c\rho}$ and assuming $\beta \geq 2$ we have:
$$ \lim_{t\to +\infty}U_t = \frac{-\beta+\sqrt{\beta^2-4}}{2c\rho}$$
by the usual convergence properties of the negative continued fractions.

Comment: I very much appreciate for your input on this! Does Ut converge to a stable solution if t is large? Many thanks!

Comment: @CharlesChou: I have just expanded and fixed my answer to reply to your last point, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: Based on your definition of Bt, I just noticed that your calculation doesn't go through. The second term for your first equation is the determinant of (\rho, \rho^2; \rho, 1+c) instead of B2 you defined. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesChou: I am quite sure the recursion are right. Start from $A_{t+1}$, for instance. Combine the first two columns as written in order to have just two non-zero elements in the first column, $c+1-\rho^2$ and $-c\rho$. Expand along the first column. You will find $(c+1-\rho^2)$ times the determinant of $A_t$ plus $c\rho$ times the determinant of a matrix like $B_t$, in which the first row is multiplied by $\rho$. The same works for $B_{t+1}$. Combining the two recursions, you get a two-terms recursion for $\det A_{t+1}$.

Comment: For short, the determinant of $(\rho,\rho^2;\rho,1+c)$ is just $\rho$ times the determinant of $B_2$, by factoring a $\rho$ out of the first row.

Comment: @CharlesChou: yes, if multiply a whole row/column of a matrix by some amount the determinant is (quite trivially) multiplied by the same amount.

Comment: Sure, my apology on that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but just to demonstrate what we're dealing with here, I've input WolframAlpha's answer for the inverses in the links below.

[Click for t=2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20matrix%20c*%5B%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%5D%5D%20%2B%20%5B%5B1%2Cp%5D%2C%5Bp%2C1%5D%5D).

[Click for t=3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20matrix%20c*%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D%20%2B%20%5B%5B1%2Cp%2Cp%5E2%5D%2C%5Bp%2C1%2Cp%5D%2C%5Bp%5E2%2Cp%2C1%5D%5D).

[Click for t=4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20matrix%20c*%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%5D%20%2B%20%5B%5B1%2Cp%2Cp%5E2%2Cp%5E3%5D%2C%5Bp%2C1%2Cp%2Cp%5E2%5D%2C%5Bp%5E2%2Cp%2C1%2Cp%5D%2C%5Bp%5E3%2Cp%5E2%2Cp%2C1%5D%5D).

Comment: If it's not an answer (but difficult to put as a comment), make this answer "community wiki".  See the check-box under the question when you edit.

Comment: Many thanks for your input, I have also tried to calculate the inverse for finite t. It turns out to be difficult to find a general form for the (1,1)-th element.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the advice, I'll be more mindful of that in the future!